# Find isometry on the cylindrical surface

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Assuming that $\sigma$ is an equidistant transformation on the cylindrical surface and $\pi$ is the covering mapping from Euclid plane to the cylindrical surface which transform $\left(x, y\right)$ to $\left(R\cos\left(x\right),R\sin\left(x\right), y \right)$, prove that there exists an equidistant transformation $\phi$ on the Euclid plane such that $\pi$ ◦ $\phi = \sigma$ ◦ $\pi$?

I find it difficult to correctly expand the $\sigma$’s domain of definition
$[0, 2\pi)\times R$ to $R^2$ to get $\phi$ and verify that $\phi$ is an equidistant transformation on the Euclid plane.

This may be a very simple question in algebraic topology but I haven't learned algebraic topology before. Is there anyone who would like to take a moment to write down how algebraic topology solves the question efficiently which may give me some guide directions in learning tools to solve the problem and even generalised problems?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> If memory serves, you asked the same question yesterday, and it got closed (and, apparently, deleted)...?

Comment: @ Andrew D. Hwang Well, I make some progress yesterday but still face some trouble now.Could you give me some hints for this question?

Comment: The larger point is, please instead edit your question instead of deleting and re-posting. Deleting wastes effort volunteers have put toward earlier versions. <> As for this specific question, are you by chance learning algebraic topology and covering spaces? If not, in what context does the question arise, and what tools are available to you?

Comment: @ Andrew D. Hwang Thank you for your comment. I won't delete and re-post afterwards. I haven't learned algebraic topology before and the question is posted by my teacher in the elementry geometry class. The tools I have are only the fact that equidistant corresponding doesn't change geodesy and the fact that the covering mapping π is an equidistant corresponding locally. Anyway, if you are available you can use advanced tools in the algebraic topology to explain the question to me plainly and I will try to learn to understand that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of considering the cylinder as a subset of $\Bbb R^3,$ I will approach it somewhat differently.

Denote the circle of radius $R$ in the complex plane by $\Bbb S,$ so our cylinder in $\Bbb R^3$ is readily isometric to $\Bbb S\times\Bbb R,$ with the map given by $\langle x,y,z\rangle\mapsto\langle x+iy,z\rangle.$ By using this map (and its inverse), we can turn any map involving the given cylinder into a corresponding map involving $\Bbb S\times\Bbb R.$ (Can you see how?)

Now, suppose our given isometry is $\sigma:\Bbb S\times\Bbb R\to\Bbb S\times\Bbb R,$ and our given covering map $\pi:\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\to\Bbb S\times\Bbb R$ is given by $\pi(t,u)=\left(Re^{it},u\right)$.

We need to show that there exists an isometry $\phi:\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\to\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ such that $\pi\circ\phi=\sigma\circ\pi.$

First, let's figure out what $\sigma$ might actually do. Geometrically, it seems obvious that it must do some combination of translation in the second variable, rotation in the first variable, reflection in the first variable, and reflection in the second variable, but can we justify this?

Note that $\sigma(R,0)=\left(Re^{it},v\right)$ for some unique $t_0\in[0,2\pi)$ and some unique $v_0\in\Bbb R.$ Now, consider the map $\rho:\Bbb S\times\Bbb R\to\Bbb S\times\Bbb R$ given by $\rho\left(Re^{it},v\right):=\left(e^{-it_0}\cdot Re^{it},v-v_0\right)$, or $\rho\left(Re^{it},v\right)=\left(Re^{i(t-t_0)},v-v_0\right)$. It can be verified that $\rho$ is an isometry on $\Bbb S\times\Bbb R,$ so that $\rho\circ\sigma$ is also an isometry on $\Bbb S\times\Bbb R,$ and furthermore, we can see that $\rho\circ\sigma$ fixes the point $(R,0).$

Next, consider the images of the points of the form $(R,u)$ under $\rho\circ\sigma.$ Note that all such points are colinear with each other, and so the images of such points under $\rho\circ\sigma$ are again colinear with each other, for if not, then $\rho\circ\sigma$ would not be an isometry. Hence, the image of the set of all such points is a line in $\Bbb S\times\Bbb R.$ In particular, since $(R,0)$ is fixed by $\rho\circ\sigma,$ then $\rho\circ\sigma$ maps the set of all such points onto itself. In particular, $\rho\circ\sigma$ maps $(R,1)\mapsto(R,\alpha)$ for some $\alpha\in\{-1,1\},$ and more generally, $\rho\circ\sigma$ maps $(R,v)\mapsto(R,\alpha v)$ for all $v\in\Bbb R.$

Next, consider the set $\bigl\{(Re^{it},0):t\in\Bbb R\bigr\}.$ Observe that the points in this set are precisely the points of $\Bbb S\times\Bbb R$ which are equidistant from $(R,1)$ and $(R,-1),$ so since the image of $\bigl\{(R,1),(R,-1)\bigr\}$ under $\rho\circ\sigma$ is itself, then the image of any such point $(Re^{it},0)$ under $\rho\circ\sigma$ is again equidistant from $(R,1)$ and $(R,-1),$ whence it is immediate that $\rho\circ\sigma$ maps $\bigl\{(Re^{it},0):t\in\Bbb R\bigr\}$ to itself. Further, we can conclude that $\rho\circ\sigma$ either maps $(Ri,0)\mapsto(Ri,0)$ or maps $(Ri,0)\mapsto(-Ri,0).$ (Can you see why?) In the former case, $\rho\circ\sigma$ maps $(Re^{it},0)\mapsto(Re^{it},0)$ for all real $t;$ in the latter case, $\rho\circ\sigma$ maps $(Re^{it},0)\mapsto(Re^{-it},0)$ for all real $t.$ Thus, there is some $\beta\in\{1,-1\}$ such that $\rho\circ\sigma$ maps $(Re^{it},0)\mapsto(Re^{i\beta t},0)$ for all real $t.$ In either case, $\rho\circ\sigma$ sends $(-R,0)$ to itself.

Again using geometric arguments, one can show that $$(\rho\circ\sigma)\left(Re^{it},v\right)=\left(Re^{i\beta t},\alpha v\right)$$ for all $t,v\in\Bbb R.$ (Can you see how?) Thus, $$\begin{eqnarray}\sigma\left(Re^{it},v\right) & = & \left(\rho^{-1}\circ\rho\circ\sigma\right)\left(Re^{it},v\right)\\ & = & \rho^{-1}\left((\rho\circ\sigma)\left(Re^{it},v\right)\right)\\ & = & \rho^{-1}\left(Re^{i\beta t},\alpha v\right)\\ & = & \left(e^{it_0}\cdot Re^{i\beta t},\alpha v+v_0\right)\\ & = & \left(Re^{i(\beta t+t_0)},\alpha v+v_0\right).\end{eqnarray}$$

There is a reflection in the first variable precisely when $\beta=-1.$ There is a reflection in the second variable precisely when $\alpha=-1.$ There is a rotation in the first variable precisely when $0<t_0<2\pi.$ There is a translation in the second variable precisely when $v_0\neq 0.$

Now that you know the general form of $\sigma,$ can you take it from there to determine an isometry $\phi$ that would satisfy the desired property?

Comment: Thank you very much!